# Select a records as list and parsing to the view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to select some data from the database and pass to the view as a list. Because Same selected data may have one or more records. So I wrote this code to select the data I wanted.

```
{
    int CurrDepId = (from e in db.CreateEmployee where e.Id == UsrIDT select new { e.Id }).First().Id;
    int CostCenterId = (from c in db.CreateDepartment where c.Id == CurrDepId select new { c.Cost_Center_Id }).First().Cost_Center_Id;

    var RelatedRequests = (from a in db.AppRequest
                           join e in db.CreateEmployee on a.Create_By equals e.Id
                           join d in db.CreateDepartment on e.DepId equals d.Id
                           join c in db.PaymentVoucher on a.Id equals c.Req_Id
                           join p in db.PaymentVoucherExpenDetails on d.Cost_Center_Id equals p.CostCenterId
                           where e.DepId != CurrDepId && p.CostCenterId == CostCenterId
                           select new 
                           {
                               e.EmpName, //string value
                               a.Created_Date.ToString(), //string value
                               d.Department,//string value
                               a.Id,//int value
                               e.UserImage // byte value
                           }).ToList();
          
  }
 Session["NewsFeed"] = RelatedRequests;
```

And then I passed it to the session.

In the session I called the list as this

```
List<SelectListItem> Newsfeed = Session["NewsFeed"] as List<SelectListItem>;
```

But when debugging In the `RelatedRequests` shows there are 4 list. But in the view, `Newsfeed` returns null. Can you guide me which part I code it wrong. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

I have sorted it myself.

I created a view model and pass the data to the viewmodel. Then from the view I called to that viewmodel and got the records.